# Tabula-py Prints the table twice

Tags: python, excel, pdf, tabula-py

My code is running but the table being printd to csv prints twice. What Can be done?

```
import tabula
tabula.convert_into("Print Invoice - 2 .pdf", "output.csv", output_format="csv",pages=1)
```

[Excel File output.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oew4O.png)

[PDF image to convert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wytd.png)

Comment: in my case code works fine. What version of `tabula` you have? Try to delete `output.csv` file and run program again

Comment: I did that same issue. version tabula_py-2.0.4

Comment: i have same version, code works fine.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the pdf that if somehow extracts its twice?

Comment: post link to you pdf and i will check this

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TP9Sk3DaV_rRrHxAcYH-p6XpWB7TgIjD/view?usp=sharing)
Link to pdf

Comment: I get the same double result as you. I think that the table in pdf is wrong formatted.

Comment: Alright, Thank you.
 If any suggestions regarding any workaround that'd be great.